# How do I find Exteranl IP of my windows system?

Tags: windows, command, ip

I have used a windows command to find this

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

and gives me an IP but if I run the same command in other pc which is in the same subnet will also give the same IP. There is no difference in both's IP.

This is same when I search in the browser as `What is my IP?`

Now How can I know My external IP address of my windows system? However I got internal IP from the command `ipconfig` which is not usefull now.

Comment: You want to look on the `router`. Usually http://192.168.0.1.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand

Comment: The `IP` address of your windows system. Is the one from `ipconfig`. The `IPv4-Address`. Good Luck.

Comment: As I know it is internal IP and cannot be accessed from other subnet

Comment: To `access` from another `subnet` you need a `router` on the `net-border`. At that `router` you are communicating with the `IPv4-Address` from `ipconfig`.

Comment: Public IP belongs to router which is connection to internet provided by ISP. All computers connected to that router would have same external IP. Your IP is unique within that router only.

Answer (score 0):

**Internal IP:**
A local Area Network Address provided by your DHCP server/ Router.

**External IP:**
A Wide Area Network address provided by your ISP(Internet service provider).

Internal IP/ LAN Address, can only be accessed within the same network. Think of babies and a mother in a house. Babies talk to each other and to their mom but don't know anything about outside. If they want any outside information, they ask their mother and mother translates the outside information to them.(NAT Translation)

Similarly, no one from outside can reach to the babies. The mother will protect her babies from anyone and everyone except she knows someone and she trusts someone what their intention is. (Port forwarding)

In your case, **it is normal** that both PC (babies) in the same LAN network have same external  IP (Mother's name/IP). If you would like to reach to a specific baby from outside, you must ask the mom and configure the mom (Your gateway router) to permit this action.

usually default gateways in a home setup are `192.168.1.1 / 192.168.2.1` You will find this information using `ipconfig`

**In Addition**, 
babies within the same household do not require mothers permission to talk to each other. They can freely communicate. However if wish to play hide-and-seek, then they need their mother's permission (UPNP settings). Where mother reveals information about one child to another.

Comment: but How do I get a external IP which is pingable from other subnet

Comment: You must explain what you are trying to achieve. that would narrow down the answer. You cannot ping a baby from the internet. you can only ping the default gateway (router/mother)

Comment: Actually I want to communicate to one of my pc which is under my subnet and from an instance of AWS(Consider it is in another subnet)

Comment: A good question will have all these information in place. First subnet address, second subnet address, IPs from <> to you are trying to reach. Edit your question with those information and you might get an answer you want